# В C# проекте отсутствует раздел References и Properties

Tags: c#, логирование

Хочу добавить логирование в проект, но по все гайдам нужно через References в NuGet найти log4net.

[image: Собственно вот]

Nlog отчаянная попытка сделать по другому .

Comment: В новых типах проектах Dependencies = Reference

Comment: Правый клик по `Dependencies`  выбрать `Manage Nuget Packages`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В новых типах проектах Dependencies = Reference .Answer by Vasek
Правый клик по Dependencies выбрать Manage Nuget Packages .Answer by Bulson